# Cannot make purchases from ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

Trying to install Steam through the software center, I click on 'Buy' and get sent to the payment service. I fill in my email address and password, hit enter and get the message: Failure in the purchase process. Sorry, something went wrong. Your payment has been canceled. Not just steam it's the same with any purchase. It's fine with free stuff. I've tried changing my password but to no avail. What I think I need is to delete my account and start from scratch
but I don't know how.

Comment: Steam is free of charge. You do not need to pay for it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Actually, the [Steam client](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) is free to install. It then asks you to buy games inside it, but that's a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug and steam cannot be installed from software center in 64 bit systems. You need either to search and install `steam:i386` (you can also install it via terminal by executing `sudo apt-get install steam`) or better download and install the deb package from the site http://store.steampowered.com/about/ (this will give you the latest package and automatically add a ppa to your system for later updates).